# Unable to start Cassandra 3.11.10 on Windows with JDK 15.0.2

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to start Cassandra 3.11.10 on Windows. I'm seeing the following error message even though I downloaded python27 and jdk15.0.2.

```
C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.10-bin\apache-cassandra-3.11.10\bin>cassandra.bat -f
Detected powershell execution permissions.  Running with enhanced startup scripts.
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

    WARNING!  Automatic page file configuration detected.
    It is recommended that you disable swap when running Cassandra
    for performance and stability reasons.

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
Failed 64-bit check. Re-running to get version from 32-bit
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

    WARNING! Detected a power profile other than High Performance.
    Performance of this node will suffer.
    Modify conf\cassandra.env.ps1 to suppress this warning.

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
Cassandra 3.0 and later require Java 8u40 or later.
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 15 is not supported. Switch to Java 8 as per the pre-requisites I documented in [Installing Cassandra](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html) and it should work. Cheers!